# C# UWP radiobutton style

Tags: c#, uwp, radio-button, styles

I have a problem with radiobutton default style at my UWP application
I used default radio button from Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls and its look like:
[image]

I read page about radiobutton at docs.microsoft and there style of radiobutton is another:
[image]

Why my radiobutton is different?
I used UWP application,min version Windows 10 Fall Creators(16299), Target version Windows 10(1803,build 17134)
My nuget packages: [image]
I can update them if need

I need something like this for my radiobuttons: [image]

Comment: May be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090099/styling-of-radio-button-in-uwp

Comment: The idea is that to take RadioButton style and customize it like you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read page about radiobutton at docs.microsoft and there style of radiobutton is another

The document style is comes from WinUI library, if you have used [`Microsoft.UI.Xaml`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml) nuget, and add the `XamlControlsResources` into application xaml, it will update radio button style automatically.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
</Application.Resources>
```

And the dark theme radio button style meet your requirement. For more detail please refer Ge[tting started with the Windows UI 2 Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started)